# Спрятать фон после отправки формы Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Всем привет))

Озадачил меня фон Bootstrap для модального окна, окно при отправке пропадает, но фон остается и убирается только перезагрузкой страницы.....
Зловредный $('.axalax-maxalay').modal("hide"); не работает....

Что может помочь?)

Форма развернута на сайте https://oreshkashop.ru/market/goods/izum_terma_bez_hvostikov/ 
в кнопке обратной связи....
Код отправки прилагаю:

```
$(function () {

 $('.btn-call').on('click', function (event) {
      // console.log("lolkrk")
      $('.callme-modal').fadeIn();

 });

 $('.callme-modal').on('click', function (event) {
      let target = event.target;
      target = target.closest('.callme-box')

      // console.log(target)
      if (!target) {
           $('.callme-modal').fadeOut();
      }
 });

 $('form').on('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var data = $(this).serialize();
      $.ajax({
           url: $(this).action,
           type: 'POST',
           data: data,
           dataType: 'text json',
           success: function (result) {
                // var response = JSON.parse(result);
                console.log(result);
           }
      });

      return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавь к конец callback `$(".modal-backdrop").fadeOut();`

```js
$('form').on('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var data = $(this).serialize();
      $.ajax({
           url: $(this).action,
           type: 'POST',
           data: data,
           dataType: 'text json',
           success: function (result) {
                // var response = JSON.parse(result);
                console.log(result);
                $(".modal-backdrop").fadeOut();
           }
      });

      return false;
 });
```

Comment: так же мне помогло добавление $('.close').click();

Answer (score 0):

Фон остается из-за классов `modal-backdrop fade show`. Я в бутстрап не силен, скорее всего предыдущий ответ поможет. Если нет, то в `success` надо прописать `$(".modal-backdrop").remove();` либо `$(".modal-backdrop").hide();`